# Drag and Drop disabled after using Install4J and starting the .exe file

Tags: javafx, install4j

Everything works great when starting the `JavaFX application from a .jar file` . I am using [Install4J](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html) with Open-Source licenses to make installers for Windows .

The exact description of the problem is this :

> Inside the application drag and drop works . Also when i drag from
>   inside the application to the Windows Explorer it also works . Just
>   for some reason dragging from Windows desktop or explorer doesn't work
>   .....

To be specific below i have photos which will help you understand exactly the problem.

> Windows 10 , [Java 9.0.4](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/java-archive-javase9-3934878.html) , [Install4J 7.0.5](https://www.ej-technologies.com/products/install4j/overview.html)

**The repository of the application is on Github in this link ( [XR3Player](https://github.com/goxr3plus/XR3Player) )**

---

Tried everything from disabling the splash screen to checking the permissions but it seems like the `Windows 10 maybe?` , system disables the application from having access to Drag and Drop , i don't know . So

1) Disabled the Splash Screen

[image]

2) Disabled ( Using SWT or QT)

[image]

3) Checking Unix Permission ( do they have to do with something ?...)

[image]

4) Starting the application from .exe file Drag and Drop disabled

[image]

5) Starting the application from .jar file the Drag and Drop works pretty well

[image]

6) Inside the application drag and drop works . Also when i drag from inside the application to the Windows Explorer it also works . Just for some reason dragging from Windows desktop or explorer doesn't work .....

[image]

7) Tried also as a console application to see if any errors are reported but still nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the "Require administrator" option in the "Windows
manifest options" of the launcher wizard causes this issue, because
drag and drop between the non-elevated desktop and your elevated application are prevented by Windows.

Comment: Thank you so much contacted Install4j support they provided a solution which i will add here :)

Comment: I actually copied the solution from the support ticket :-)

Comment: Oouuuu you are in the support mail LOVE thanks you so much.

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS could you please post the solution here?

Comment: @MissChanandlerBong The answer is the solution: The "Require administrator" setting shouuld not be selected in the "Executable info->Windows manifest options" step of the launcher wizard.

Comment: @IngoKegel Thank you. Actually, I experience this problem when launch4j. I have to keep the manifest option for my software to work. Should I post a separate question about this case with launch4j?