# Intellij stop JavaFX drag and drop

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I have this Application:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage){

    Text fileText = new Text("File:");

    TextField fileField = new TextField();
    fileField.setPromptText("Drop file here");
    fileField.setEditable(false);
    fileField.setMinWidth(250);
    fileField.setOnDragOver((e) -> {
        if (e.getGestureSource() != fileField && e.getDragboard().hasFiles()) {
            e.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.COPY_OR_MOVE);
        }
        e.consume();
    });
    fileField.setOnDragDropped(e -> {

        Dragboard db = e.getDragboard();
        boolean success = false;
        if (db.hasFiles()){

            fileField.setText(db.getFiles().toString());
            success = true;

        }

        e.setDropCompleted(success);
        e.consume();

    });

    Button clearButton = new Button("Clear");
    clearButton.setOnMouseClicked(e -> fileField.setText(""));

    HBox hboxFile = new HBox();
    hboxFile.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
    hboxFile.getChildren().addAll(fileText, fileField, clearButton);

    HBox.setMargin(fileText, new Insets(10));
    HBox.setMargin(fileField, new Insets(10, 10, 10, 0));
    HBox.setMargin(clearButton, new Insets(10, 10, 10, 0));

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(hboxFile));
    primaryStage.sizeToScene();
    primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
    primaryStage.show();

}
```

[image]

My problem is at drag and drop in input.

If I run application from Intellij, drag and drop not work.

[image]

If I create runnable-jar and execute separated by Intellij, it works.

I use Java 10 Oracle.

Why Intellij block drag and drop of JavaFX?

Comment: Interesting. Maybe you can live with copy & paste.

Comment: @JoopEggen what do you mean?

Comment: To still run the application inside IntelliJ IDEA you might copy the file, and paste it in the text field.

Comment: I don't have access to Java 10 at the moment. However, I cannot reproduce the problem with OpenJDK 11.0.2 + OpenJFX 11-13 on Windows 10. This includes both running the application via IntelliJ and via Gradle.

Comment: Try suggestions from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50437739/drag-and-drop-disabled-after-using-install4j-and-starting-the-exe-file/50564610#50564610

Comment: @Andrey I don't find something to help me.